# Create a buffered copy of WCF Message

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have the following code in a message inspector to examine the response body. I understand the WCF Message can only be read once so I create a copy first. But with the following code I still get the error "This message cannot support the operation because it has been read."...Am I missing something?

```
        MessageBuffer buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        Message copy = buffer.CreateMessage();
        message = copy;

        XmlDictionaryReader bodyReader = copy.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
        bodyReader.ReadStartElement("Binary");
        byte[] bodyBytes = bodyReader.ReadContentAsBase64();
        string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyBytes);

        return messageBody;
```

Also I don't feel comfortable using Int23.MaxValue there. What would be a reasonable size?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    MessageBuffer buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
    message = buffer.CreateMessage();

    var copy = buffer.CreateMessage();
    XmlDictionaryReader bodyReader = copy.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
    bodyReader.ReadStartElement("Binary");
    byte[] bodyBytes = bodyReader.ReadContentAsBase64();
    string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyBytes);

    return messageBody;
```

Comment: The `message` variable is passed into your code by reference and contains the message WCF will work with. It cannot be in a "already read" state to be valid for WCF use. You can, however, call `buffer.CreateMessage()` multiple times to create clones of the actual message WCF is working with. If you want to inject something into the existing message, you can create a new message from the old message and pass the modified message back to WCF.